# Xcode 6.3 reports Test Succeeded for failing test

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, xcode6.3

Has anyone else noticed that Xcode 6.3 (6D570) is showing the "Test Succeeded" popup (and displaying the test success sound, if configured) for a failing test when you run the test by itself?

When you run all tests in the file, everything works as expected.

For example, the following assertion fails, but Xcode shows "Test Succeeded".

```
XCTAssertTrue([queryStringLat isEqualToNumber:expectedLat], @"Expected: %@ but got: %@\n", expectedLat, queryStringLat);
```

The debugger output shows that it failed, Xcode just seems to be getting confused.

Here is the debugger output:

```
Foo_Tests.m: test failure: -[Foo_Tests test_sendRequestForApp_with_coordinates_validate_that_coordinates_exist] failed: (([queryStringLat isEqualToNumber:expectedLat]) is true) failed - Expected: 37.33233 but got: 0
```

Has anyone else experienced the same type of thing?

This isn't a huge "bug", but is *really* annoying when working on tests.

Thanks!

Comment: File a radar at bugreporter.apple.com.

Comment: I filed a bug report yesterday.  Based upon past experience with Apple's bug reporting system, I'll never find out much more about the bug, unless they need more information.  Hoping to find out if anyone else has had similar experience and possibly a fix/work-aroundd.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

I received a response from Apple. They said that they could not reproduce the problem, and asked me to remove all plugins and provide them with a complete sample of code that reproduced the issue.

Hmm, PLUGINS, brilliant!

I started to remove plugins, a few at a time, and after a few attempts, the "bug" went away!

I then tracked it down to the MCLog plugin, which I had installed using the Alcatraz package manager in Xcode.

I've also filed an issue with the MCLog author.

If I find out, or figure out, exactly what was causing this issue, I'll post that information here.  I find it interesting that MCLog was able to confuse Xcode so it reported "Test Succeeded" upon failures.